# How do I keep chocolate chips from melting in cake batter?

Tags: cake, chocolate

I have attempted to put chocolate chips in cake batter, but they always melt. Bakeries are able to make chocolate chip cakes and the chips are still somewhat solid. Mine come out almost diluted.

Comment: Have you tried freezing them before adding to your batter? What kind of chips are you using?

Comment: How big are your chocolate chips?

Comment: They take a while to firm up again even after the cake is apparently cool. Commercially produced cakes will usually have cooled down fully before you get them. If you look at the chips carefully they've clearly softened and only approximately held their shape.

Comment: Your question is somewhat vaguely worded (what chips? what does "melt" mean, do they get completely mixed with the batter, or do they stay softish after the cake is ready?). In any case, this is highly related and possibly even a duplicate: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21171/why-do-chocolate-chips-stay-softer-after-being-baked.

Comment: Also: milk chocolate or plain?  Milk chocolate becoimes runnier when meted (it also has a slightly lower melting point but probably not enough to matter when compared to the temperature that a cake reaches inside)

Comment: Mm I wonder, I always thought [those](http://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Large/t_3/00g/999999-Chipits%20Semi%20Sweet%20300g.jpg) chips were meltier than [these](http://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Enlarge/_93/984/93984.jpg). The second ones hold their shape better in my experience, but they taste very different.

Answer (score 1):

My experience tells me that the better the chocolate is, the faster it would melt.  I would suggest to lightly coat the chips in some flour and then add them to the mix.

Let me know if this works, will ya?